# Write text on background-image

Tags: html, css

I try to make an image for a whole site. It works! But I need something more, I try to make site on this image. I need to make divs on it. I try to do it that:

```html
<html lang="PL-pl">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>EU-Trans system</title>
 <style>
  html{
   background: url('http://monster.pwoj.pl/images/main_background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
  }
 </style>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row">
   ASDF
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But there is white background in the div place. How to remove it?

Comment: It seems your code is working as expected[without white space]. Copied your code and tried in Chrome "https://plnkr.co/edit/u34fBM2dlJkCbqYOmSlf?p=preview"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your style to body instead of html

```
body{
    background: url('http://monster.pwoj.pl/images/main_background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove **background-color: #fff;** from the body.
Or add **background: transparent;**

Comment: I had to change html on body.